# Python look-alike-but-different functions to be aware of

Tags: python

I've just noticed that [`numpy.random.randint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html) and [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randint) have very similar names but they have slightly different definitions. Randomness and performance differences aside, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029993/differences-between-numpy-random-and-random-random-in-python?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061738/how-do-random-number-generation-methods-differ-in-python), I'm surprised that the end number for `numpy.random` is exclusive while in `random` is inclusive.

Looking at the documentation

> **`numpy.random.randint(low, high=None, size=None, dtype='l')`**
>       Return random integers from low (inclusive) to high (exclusive).

while

> **`random.randint(a, b)`**:
>     Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b. Alias for `randrange(a, b+1).`

I must say that `random` convention to include `b` is less pythonic, as it feels inconsistent with, say, `range`.

In any case, my question is **What other examples of common look-alike but different functions I must be aware of?**

Comment: Anyone can define an function however they like.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Yes, but the question asks about "common" functions, and implicitly this means functions from the standard library and/or widely-used third party libraries such as numpy.

Comment: @kaya3. Yes. That's exactly what I meant.